# UWP C# Add Button Dynamically and Organizing On StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I understand there are a few post asking about adding buttons dynamically but I could not find out how to organize them on the `stackpanel`. 
I have no issue adding new buttons but is there any way to organize them in column and row?

```
<Grid Margin="400,0,0,0">
     <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel">
          <Button x:Name="Button" Height="30" Width="100" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button(); ;
        stackpanel.Children.Add(b);
        b.Content = "Button";
    }
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Update:
I'd like to add button(s) based on how many times the button is clicked. It adds until 4th rom then move to the next/new column.[image]

Comment: Can you specify, what you mean with: "organize them in columan and row"

Comment: I think you are asking for `ItemsControl`

Comment: @TheTanic I have added the illustration of how the intended buttons layout. Could you please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @mylim Grid is the solution for you, why dont you use it?

Comment: @Cheese I understand i can create grid in XAML.. but how to create it dynamically based on how many times i click the button.

Comment: Either take a Grid like @Cheese recommended. Othwerwise you could use nested StackPanels

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez i have to say I am not still quite new to UWP & C#..  I just read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol I got a bit confused with the methods..  & which is applicable.

Comment: @TheTanic thanks.. I will read up the nested stackpanel ...

Comment: @mylim take a look at my answer, to see a grid solution for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments i took, that it is possbile to use a `Grid` too. To achieve the desired layout you could use the following:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Margin="400,0,0,0">
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="addBtn" Height="30" Width="100" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,0" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I replaced your `StackPanel` with a `Grid` and added definitions for the four rows and the first column.

**CS:**

First we need to add a counter:

```
public int buttonCounter = 1;
```

Then we need to change the `Button_Click` method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Create the button
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Height = 30;
            b.Width = 100;
            b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            b.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0);
            b.Content = "Button " + buttonCounter;
            b.Click += Button_Click;

            //Calculate the place of the button
            int column = (int)(buttonCounter / 4);
            int row = buttonCounter % 4;

            //Check if you need to add a columns
            if(row == 0)
            {
                ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
                col.Width = new GridLength(column, GridUnitType.Auto);
                myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
            }

            //Add the button
            myGrid.Children.Add(b);
            Grid.SetColumn(b, column);
            Grid.SetRow(b, row);
            buttonCounter++;
        }
```

Inside this method, the position of the new button is automatically calculated and if needed, a new column is added to the grid.

Comment: I have tested your code ,but the first button is in the second row. `Grid.SetRow(b, row);` starts from row 1. I have updated `buttonCounter =0` and removed the default `ColumnDefinition`. @TheTanic

Comment: Thanks @MichaelXu-MSFT ... after exploring the code.. it brings me to another question is that how do I control these dynamically created button(s)' event? eg. button 1 to turns on LED 1, button 2 turns on LED 2 etc.

Comment: to remove a button `myGrid.Children.Remove(b);` how do I specify the respective button to removed & after removed how to realign the rows & column so there is no empty space between. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Thanks for your suggestions. But it needs to start with row1, because we have one button initial in our xaml. Also we need the default ColumnDefinition, because when we remove it, the first created in codebehind is handled as first and not second.

Comment: @mylim Please create **new** questions to solve your **new** problems. I am glad that i could help you with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <Grid Margin="400,0,0,0">
       <UniformGrid x:Name="ButtonsUniformGrid" Columns="2" Rows="4"/>
    </Grid>
```

If you need to have a button at the beginning, when you initialize your view do the following:

```
    Button b = new Button(); ;
    b.Content = "Button";
    b.Click += Button_Click;
    ButtonsUniformGrid.Children.Add(b);
```

Then, everytime you click on it will put a new button in the grid. Let me know if you have any other questions about this :)

---

As commented `Uwp` doesn't include `UniformGrid` if you don't specify it in your xaml. If you want to use it, just include this:

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

and your `UniformGrid` will be like this:

```
<controls:UniformGrid...../>
```

Comment: UniformGrid is not included in the vanilla UWP. You should add an informations, that this is from the [CommuniyToolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/)

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can use it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid - and if my answer solves the op problem it's kinda simpler thant the other one

Comment: Still not correct. First you need install the Toolkit from nugget package