# UWP C# How To Handle Event for Dynamically Created Button(s) and Control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

in relation to the post [UWP C# Add Button Dynamically and Organizing On StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737121/uwp-c-sharp-add-button-dynamically-and-organizing-on-stackpanel/52740086?noredirect=1#comment92430217_52740086) I have additional questions

1. how do I control these dynamically created button(s)' event? eg. button 1 to turns on LED 1, button 2 to turns on LED 2 etc.
2. how to selectively remove the button(s) and reorganize the remaining buttons with no empty spaces in between.

Thank you.

Update:
I have a routine to add the client with details such as `client IP` etc. from the client and to add and display them in a `scrollviewer`. 
How do i link either the `clientname` or `client ip` to the dictionary?

```
private async void AddClientList()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            ClientListUserControl clientListControl = new ClientListUserControl(this, new ClientList(clientName, receiveIP, DateTime.Now, receivePort, receiveService, receiveDEV, receiveSTS, receiveACT));
            ClientList_Panel.Children.Add(clientListControl);
            clientListControl.updateDisplay();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Normally you should have each question in a single thread... But nevertheless: To question one: Does the LED number to turn on always is the same of the button number (The one in the name)? To question 2: When I delete button 3, is button 4 going to be button 3 and so on, or do they only switch positions?
And the most important: What did you try so far?

Comment: @TheTanic Hi, LED(s) is an example I use for the scenario. In detailed, I am displaying Remote IoT Clients to a Host which is where the button(s) are. Each of the client(s) connected will add additional button(s) respectively and other control indicator(s) (eg. device connection status etc.) Once the respective button(s) is clicked, it will trigger an output pin at the respective client. In a way, the name for the client(s) are saved in a .json file which I will bind to the button(s). Once button is deleted, it doesn't require to sync the name but just to close up the gap. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use **[Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Tag)** property of Button to pass the parameter. This property is inherited from FrameworkElement, and generally it is used to get or set an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this object.

Please refer to following code.

```
    private void ButtonCreateNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Height = 30;
        b.Width = 100;
        b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        b.Margin = new Thickness(6, 6, 6, 6);
        b.Content = "Button " + buttonCounter;
        b.Tag = "LED-" + buttonCounter;
        b.Click += Button_Click;

        ....

        buttonCounter++;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var led = btn.Tag;
        //use led_name as a parameter here, according with this variable to turn on the LED
        TurnOnOffLed(led);
    }
```

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT Thanks. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

**To your first question:** 
To handle this, you should introduce a dictionary, where the button is the key and your value is the client. So you can get the linked client in the ClickHandler.

```
public Dictionary<Button, object> clientDict = new Dictionary<Button, object>();
```

**Note**: Here the type of the client is object, because I don`t know what type you have!

You add the button inside of your AddButton routine. Again: I dont know where you get your client from, so I added the value `null`. Change this to fulfil your requirements. Then you add another ClickHandler and get the linked client:

```
 b.Click += HandleButtonClick;
 clientDict.Add(b, null);



 private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Execute whatever you want from your client:
            var client = clientDict[sender as Button];
        }
```

**To your second question:**
You need to add a RemoveMethod, where you get the column and row of the button, which should be deleted. Afterwards you can manipulate all other buttons column and row property. To avoid, that a new added button is not aligned to the others, you need to change the add-process, to make the position of the new button depending on the number of elements in your dictionary. Here an example how the full code could look like:

```
public int buttonCounter = 1;
public Dictionary<Button, object> clientDict = new Dictionary<Button, object>();

private void RemoveBtn(Button button)
{
    var row = Grid.GetRow(button);
    var column = Grid.GetColumn(button);

    //Rearange
    foreach (var btn in clientDict.Keys)
    {
        var r = Grid.GetRow(btn);
        var c = Grid.GetColumn(btn);

        if (c > column || (c == column && r > row))
        {
            if (r != 0)
            {
                //Set the row new
                Grid.SetRow(btn, r - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                //Need to set it to a new column
                Grid.SetRow(btn, 3);
                Grid.SetColumn(btn, c - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    myGrid.Children.Remove(button);
    clientDict.Remove(button);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //Create the button
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Height = 30;
    b.Width = 100;
    b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    b.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0);
    b.Content = "Button " + buttonCounter;
    b.Click += HandleButtonClick;
    clientDict.Add(b, null);

    //Calculate the place of the button
    int column = (int)(clientDict.Count / 4);
    int row = clientDict.Count % 4;

    //Check if you need to add a columns
    if (row == 0 && myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count <= column)
    {
        ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
        col.Width = new GridLength(column, GridUnitType.Auto);
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
    }

    //Add the button
    myGrid.Children.Add(b);
    Grid.SetColumn(b, column);
    Grid.SetRow(b, row);
    buttonCounter++;
}

private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Execute whatever you want from you handler:
    var client = clientDict[sender as Button];
}
```

**Note:** The rearrange process is not performance optimized.

Comment: Thanks. To add the client to the dictionary, how do i link it as an object?

Comment: Every object in C# extends object. But if you know the type of your client-objects, you can change the Value-Type, when you create dictionary

Comment: in my case the `clientname` is a `string` therefore `public Dictionary<Button, string> clientDict = new Dictionary<Button, string>();` ?

Comment: Yes you could do so. If it is a simple string, you can check the other answer, where the tag is used to store the string, but then you have to rewrite the add of the buttons, because there i reuse the dictionary