# UWP C# Bind JSON items to Button MenuFlyout

Tags: c#, json, xaml, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

i have a dynamic list of client devices which will be added over the network. Once they are connected their details are save in JSON file. 
I would like to have an additional display and control of the client device(s) where I click on a `Add` button with a `MenuFlyout` populated with the list of the client device(s)'s `ClientName` from the JSON file. Once the `menuitem` is selected, it will add a button and connection status indicator (eg. connected, disconnected or error) for the respective client device selected on a grid. 
[This is what I have did for adding the button but couldn't figure out how to bind to the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737121/uwp-c-sharp-add-button-dynamically-and-organizing-on-stackpanel?noredirect=1#comment92404726_52737121)

Please help.
Thanks.

my json class is created in a separate .cs [image: json file]
I am not sure did I do it correctly at `MenuFlyoutItem_Click` where `item.clientname` has an error.

The `json` file `clientslist.txt` i have checked for the format it seems correct. [image: The JSON file]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to following code. I have not found a way with using *Binding* or *x:Bind*,but we can add the MenuFlyoutItem to the MenuFlyout manually after the json data deserialized.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var deviceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeviceInfo>>(jsonData);
        var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
        foreach (var device in deviceList)
        {
            var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.DeviceName, Text = device.DeviceName };
            menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.DeviceName;
            menuFlyoutItem.Click += MenuFlyoutItem_Click;
            menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
        }

        ButtonCreateDevice.Flyout = menuFlyout;
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        var deviceName = item.DeviceName;

        //TO DO SOMETHING
    }
```

DeviceInfo class defined as:

```
    class DeviceInfo
    {
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; };
    }
```

Tested with the sample data(**jsonData**) as:

```
[{"DeviceName":"LED-1","Status":"Connected"},{"DeviceName":"LED-2","Status":"Connected"},{"DeviceName":"LED-3","Status":"Connected"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MichealXU-MSFT to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` I will have to install `NewtonSoft.Json` `nuget` right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This library is used to deserialize json string to object or serialize object to json string.

Comment: hi @MichealXu-MSFT I am not sure did I do it correctly at `MenuFlyoutItem_Click` where `item.clientname` has an error.

Comment: @mylim, you should use item.Tag to because you set the value with `menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientname`.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT another thing is that in your example `jsonData` would be the `json` file. in my case i declared as `public static string CLIENTSLIST = "clientslist.txt";` which `var deviceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientList>>(CLIENTSLIST);` but when i click at the button, unhandled exception occured on the line `unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path", line 0, position 0`

Comment: @mylim, the error may be caused by the incorrect json format. Could you please provide the file(clientslist.txt) content?

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT please find the link for `clientslist.txt` in the followling link https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnzY25rC-8Zkj90Y-pBMLu9pJdWYKQ I have checked the JSON with https://jsoneditoronline.org/ data format seems correct.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT is there any issue as previously my JSON code is written `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;` to save my `json` file instead of `newtonsoft.json` 

`public async Task saveClientInfoToJSON(List<ClientList> clientLists)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientList>));
            using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(CLIENTSLIST, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, clientLists);
            }
        }`

Comment: @mylim, in your code, the variable `CLIENTSLIST` is a string with content `clientslist.txt`,but not the json string content. You should read the file of clientslist.txt.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT i am not very sure about `newtonsoft.json` however i used `serialization.json` method to do it.. i have posted my answer.. i am not sure if it's optimized... please advise ... thanks.

Comment: @mylim, `Serialization.Json` is also available for serializing and deserializing JSON data. It is up to you. I think how to or use which library to serialize and deserialize JSON data is another topic against your original post.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT Thanks. I am just confused with the differences. Glad that I am able to get it to work now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to use `serialization.json` to do it

```
 private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ClientList> clientLists;
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientList>));
        try
        {
            var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CLIENTSLIST);

            clientLists = (List<ClientList>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
            var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();

            foreach (var device in clientLists)
            {
                var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.clientname, Text = device.clientname };
                menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientname;
                menuFlyoutItem.Click += MenuFlyoutItem_Click;
                menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
            }
            AddButton.Flyout = menuFlyout;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Do nothing, file doesn't exist
        }
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        var deviceName = item.Tag;

        //TO DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

[image]